# How do I create a Google Sitemap for my ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, sitemap

I'm using **DotNetNuke**, so the whole site is basically dynamically driven and I'm clueless to how to go about creating a Google sitemap for it.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jeff Atwood has some good information on SiteMaps [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001174.html).  You can also see more information on SiteMap formats [here](http://sitemaps.org/protocol.php).

Comment: Jeff doesn't say how he did his sitemaps... just how it's important.

Comment: I agree that Jeff's entry does not go into the details of how he created the Stack Over Flow sitemap, but it is a good jumping off point to get more information including the schema.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I already read his post which is why I've jumped on the sitemap bandwagon. :)

Answer (score 4):

DotNetNuke out of the box will create it for you if you are working with DNN 4.5.x and later (I believe that was the version).

Just point google to

http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap.aspx

For example here [is my site map](http://iowacomputergurus.com/sitemap.aspx).

It isn't perfect, but works quite well, you can use some other tools to create it as well, but you will need something that spiders the site to get that.

*Update*

I thought I would expand a bit as to why it isn't perfect.

1. All pages are given the same priority
2. It only grabs actual pages, no third party modules that generate "pages" will be captured and included (Blogs, Ventrian News Articles, Forums etc).

Depending on your needs [BiteTheBullet.co.uk](http://www.bitethebullet.co.uk) has a nice free provider,  [Ifinity](http://www.ifinity.com.au) also has a good one as well that includes some of the "missed" content.

Comment: Thanks, I agree it's not perfect. I actually found a great sitemap generator over a codeplex. If anyone is interested you can check it out here http://www.codeplex.com/sitemapgenerator

Answer (score 1):

You can try this [DotNetNuke Google Sitemap Generator](http://www.bitethebullet.co.uk/tabid/59/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. I've found a great sitemap generator over at codeplex. If anyone is interested you can check it out here: http://www.codeplex.com/sitemapgenerator

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Also see this that I distribute.

It is better than all the other in the fact that it's extensible by plugging in new providers for individual modules.  This allows you to index all of the Urls for a particular module.

Free add-ons include providers for the Blog module and the Ventrian News Articles module.

[Free DotNetNuke Sitemap Provider Download](http://www.ifinity.com.au/Products/Google_Sitemap_For_DNN/)